# Is this if needed?

Tags: objective-c

This method is generated by Xcode 3.2 using "Accessor defs to clipboard"

```
- (void)setBodyMass:(int)newBodyMass {
    if (bodyMass != newBodyMass) {
        bodyMass = newBodyMass;
    }
}
```

Could I just as easily write this as you see below? It seems to be doing a conditional test to save it doing a possible redundant assignment.

```
- (void)setBodyMass:(int)newBodyMass {
        bodyMass = newBodyMass;
}
```

cheers -gary-

Comment: Well if it's already set to the same value I don't see why you should reset it.

Comment: IIRC, this is a just a style guideline. It keeps you from accidently forgetting to call [bodyMass release] before assignment.

Comment: I can see why for an object (like an NSString) because if you don't test there you run the risk of releasing the object. But in this situation, it just seems to boil down to the overhead of an "if" compared to the frequency of setting duplicate values.

Comment: [bodyMass release] now I am confused, its an int? i'm certainly no expert but I was not expecting to have to release an int.

Comment: Your code is fine; ints need not be (indeed, cannot be) released.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you do a check like that in a mutator method because you're working with objects that have to be `release`d. Say you have a mutator method without that check:

```
- (void)setObject:(MyObject *)anObj
{
    [obj release];
    obj = [anObj retain];
}
```

Imagine (for some reason) you have a chunk of code like this that uses that method:

```
MyObject *o = [MyObject object];    // Auto-released
[anotherObject setObject:o];
[anotherObject setObject:o];
```

On Line 1, you can assume `o` has a retain count of 0 (since it's autoreleased). On Line 2, `o` has been passed to `setObject:`, which retains it and stores it in the instance variable `obj`. Since we're working with pointers, `o` and `obj` point to the same object in memory, which now has a retain count of 1.

On Line *3*, you pass the *same* object to `setObject:` *again*. But right away in that method, you release `anObj`, *which is the same object that both `o` and `obj` point to!* This means that `o`, `obj`, and `anObj` have a retain count of *0*. When you set `obj` to `[obj retain]`, you're making `obj` point to an object that has been released already.

This is obviously bad, so when working with mutator methods that deal with objects, you should always use that guard, which effectively checks to see if `obj` and `anObj` point to the same object in memory; if they do, nothing happens.

*However*, this guard isn't necessary in your example, because you're passing an `int` -- not a pointer -- and `int`s, of course, never get released (since they're not objects).

Comment: Thanks Michael (I am guessing thats right) a very clear exceptional answer, as usual :) many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it your way; assigning an `int` is very cheap. The check makes sense if the assignment is to some large data structure or might have unintended side effects, neither of which is true for `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Does the assignment cause something to trigger (event)? Doesn't seem so. You can compare but for a simple int I do not think it's an obligation to verify if the value is the same or not. Of course, if you want to display something to the user concerning that he has entering the same value, you might check the value, otherwise, I would not check it.